# modificar año automáticamente dentro de un input

Tags: javascript, html, input

tengo un input tipo text, con un value "31/12/2023" readonly quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que dentro del input se modifique automáticamente el año pero el mes y el día queden iguales, tengo algo así:

```
<div class="form-group has-float-label">
 <input tabindex="8" name="txtFechaFinal" type="text" value="31/12/2023" id="fechaFinal" autocomplete="off" readonly placeholder=" " class="form-control InputPading limpiar" required/>
</div>
```

Comment: Se modifique bajo que criterio?

Comment: Que tome el año del equipo del cliente?

Comment: Que *"se modifique automáticamente el año"* ¿a qué? ¿A un año mas?  ¿A diez años menos? ¿A números romanos?. Intenta asignarle el valor con javascript después de cargar la página.

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende... por favor, se más específico.

Comment: lo que necesito es que el año se modifique automáticamente por ejemplo este es 2023, el siguiente 2024 ya si sucesivamente, pero el día y el mes quede por default 31/12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes obtener la fecha en javascript o en un script haciendo:

```
    var today = new Date();
    var anyoActual = today.getFullYear();
    var nuevoValor = "31/12/" + anyoActual;
    //Y luego asignarle este valor a tu input por JS 
    
    $('#id').val(nuevoValor);
    //En caso de que no tengas JQuery, puedes hacerlo con vanilla JS asi:
    document.getElementById("id").value=nuevoValor;
```

Para hacer esto lo único que necesitas es ponerle un id a tu input de modo que quede así:

```
 <input tabindex="8" id="txtFechaFinal" name="txtFechaFinal" type="text" value="31/12/2023" id="fechaFinal" autocomplete="off" readonly placeholder=" " class="form-control InputPading limpiar" required/>
```

Espero que te sea util.

Comment: Quiero entender que da respuesta a lo del año su ultimo comentario, que ahora quiere 2023 y a continuación 2024. Respecto al JQuery tienes razón, modificare la respuesta para que peda hacerse con vanilla, pero creo que borrar la respuesta no es necesario, al final cabe la posibilidad de que le sea útil. y no me cuesta nada dejarla

Comment: Pues creo que tu respuesta es buena, ahí tienes mi positivo. Y mi agradecimiento, gente como tu aporta y ayuda a la comunidad. Tenemos mucho que aprender de gente que se esfuerza y ayuda tanto como tu lo haces

Comment: fue de mucha utilidad la respuesta, justo era lo que necesitaba y funcionó correctamente, muchas gracias!!!!!!!